# <video> tag is working in chrome but not in firefix..What is the problem?

Tags: tags

```
  <video> tag is working in chrome but not in Firefox ..I have the Firefox version 56.0.2 ..What is the problem?
   <div id="myvideo" class="lp-video-wrapper">
    <div class="video-wrap hidden-xs">
      <video autoplay="" loop="" id="usbvideo" tabindex="0" class="al-img100">
        <source src="174125357.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="174125357.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I mean Firefox*

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285921/html5-video-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not specifically related to WordPress.

To answer your question, you need to convert the video in "ogg" format and add it to make it work on Firefox. Here is the code:

```
<video autoplay="" loop="" id="usbvideo" tabindex="0" class="al-img100">
        <source src="174125357.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="174125357.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="174125357.ogg" type="video/ogg>
</video>
```

There are tons of converters available for this. I tried http://www.zamzar.com/convert/mp4-to-ogg/ and it works well.